# Error: Missing helper: "generateDate.date"

Tags: node.js

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({

    helpers: {
        generateDate: (date, format) => {
            return moment(date).format(format)
        }
    }

})
app.engine("handlebars", expressHandlebars({
    handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars),
    helpers: {
        generateDate: (date, format) => {
            return moment(date).format(format)
        }
    }
}))

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

app.engine("handlebars", expressHandlebars({
    handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
}), exphbs());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

---

{{generateDate date 'MMM DD YYYY'}}

---

Error: Missing helper: "generateDate.date"